# What does "tripped over her head" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, figurative-language

"The fireflies had arrived, making everyone she passed appear a little enchanted as their laughter and flirtations tripped over her head."

[Finale
Caraval Series Book 3
By Stephanie Garber · 2019 Chapter 24](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Finale/KD5fDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22laughter%20and%20flirtations%20tripped%20over%20her%20head%22&pg=PT132&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Did you try a dictionary? It's not the prime meaning, but it's in there.

Comment: Please tell us the source of quotations!

Comment: I've added a link and a citation.  You must always do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unusual use of the verb *to trip.* I think it must be the sense *walk, run, or dance with quick light steps* rather than *fall over something.* The sounds of other people's 'laughter and flirtations' floating over the protagonist's head are compared to someone running daintily through the air.

Comment: https://youtu.be/oZ9WKQmcX2k?si=qfbvbJo9gpyS46a4